# What is a function/How to distinguish a function in MIPS?

Tags: function, mips

Extremely new to MIPs assembly language -- I haven't been able to find a link that specifically **tells** you what a function is distinguished as in MIPS, examples of how we use jal, jr, etc..

It's very difficult to find out how these actions work -- My text book for this section of the course is very broad and assumes I already know the language and just outlines a code (under the assumption that I know exactly what the code means)

Hence, the book isn't helping me so I'm trying to practice on my own..

Anywho, in my class we wrote a simple array code which supposedly has a "function" in it.

My question is -- how do I know what is the "function" 
Below is a code we did in class -- it's supposed to output an array from 1 to 10.. I understand where it increments and such (addi) and why it's a 1 and 4 but I don't understand 
what $ra, jal , jr mean... but I'm assuming that these have something to do with what a "function" is

```
#Load an array and display

    .data

    .align 2
a1:     .space 40

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    la $s0, a1
    jal loadArray
    la $s0, a1# <- return here after function return
    jal displayArray
    # <- return here after 2nd function
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

displayArray:
    #$ra = the address of line 14
    li $t0, 1   #int i = 0
    displayLoop: blt $t0, 11, display
        #else
        jr $ra
    display:
        lw $t0, ($s0)   # a1[i] = i;

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall

    #incremment i and array pointer
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    addi $s0, $s0, 4

    j displayLoop

loadArray:
    #$ra = the address of line 14
    li $t0, 1   #int i = 0
    loadLoop: blt $t0, 11, load
        #else
        jr $ra
    load:
        sw $t0, ($s0)   # a1[i] = i;

        #incremment i and array pointer
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        addi $s0, $s0, 4

        j loadLoop
```

So this is the sample code but the only difference between this code and a usual code with just labels is the jump register and jump and link...
Does that distinguish what is a function???

Sorry for the long wall of text -- TL;DR  In MIPS, how do you know what is a "function"  I know what a label is (obv.) but not a function...

This isn't as straight forward to me as it is in cpp or java lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *function* (or *subroutine*) is really just any piece of code that you can *call* (with `jal`) and expect to return to you (with `jr $ra`). It is also generally expected to keep your stack and registers intact across the call.

The term *function* is used more often by high-level languages like C, whereas *subroutine* is more common at the assembly-language level.

`jal` means "Jump And Link" - I would expect this to be covered in your textbook. This instruction **1)** stores the return address (the address of the instruction *after* the `jal`) in `$ra`, the *link register* (or *return address register*) and then **2)** jumps to the target address.  This is how you *call* a function.

When the function is finished, it *returns* to the caller by jumping to the address in the *return address register*, with the `jr $ra` instruction (Jump to Register `$ra`).

Your comments imply that you already understand this:

```
jal loadArray
la $s0, a1# <- return here after function return
jal displayArray
# <- return here after 2nd function
```

So `loadArray` can be considered a function, as can `displayArray`.

Read more:

- [Subroutines/Functions in MIPS](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~xujie/cs447/Mips/sub.html)
- [MIPS Quick Tutorial](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm)
- [MIPS Instruction Reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)
- [MIPS Assembly/Control Flow Instructions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Control_Flow_Instructions)
- [`jal` and `jr`](http://user.it.uu.se/~justin/Teaching/NewDarkSlides/lecture5.pdf)

Comment: Those were the comments I wrote in when the TA explained that specific line.  But yeah, I understand it now. Thanks!

Comment: @user3377643 You're welcome. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to up-vote any answer that assist you, and accept the one that best solves your problem.

Comment: Also, thanks for the extra webpages on the info!  It helps a LOT. Also yeah I'm new to the site, didn't know how to upvote stuff but I did now :D.